# CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting returns empty string in production?

Tags: c#, azure

I've just upgraded my project to Azure Tools 1.8 (October 2012 SDK) and I'm running into a strange issue;

In my WorkerRole my calls to `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` returns null (can be empty string, hard to tell from log file). In other words; I can't fetch settings from the RoleEnvironment.

Info:

- Emulator/localhost works perfect
- Verified dll-version via RDP
- Tried to fetch various testsettings
- The same lines of code is running just fine in the production slot right now.
- I'm using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.8.0.0 from nuget
- Added setting to app.config also to test, same result.

Any clues?

**Update:**

Calling code (method Run() in WorkerRole)

```
public override void Run(){

   // Fetch connectionstring
   var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionString");

   // connectionString is null here?

  [...]

}
```

The setting is visible in the portal so it is certainly deployed.

Comment: Does the setting you are trying to retrieve actually appear in the Portal service configuration settings (i.e. did the setting get deployed)?  Share the code in question?

Comment: Yes it does. I updated with the calling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed it, the following steps solved it:

- One of the projects referenced `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration` version 1.7.0.0. Changed this (strange if this is the cause though since the dll in the output where the correct version. Maybe it was loaded from GAC at runtime?)
- Removed assembly binding redirects for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration`
- Upgraded the `osFamily` from 1 to 2 (Windows 2008 SP2 -> Windows 2008 R2)

Some steps are probably unnecessary but I'm not sure which of them :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about using RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("ConnectionString") instead; assuming you are trying to get a value from service configuration file (cscfg) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had updated the project to use Azure SDK 2.0. I updated NuGet packages for my web and worker roles, but the Azure project in Visual Studio was still on the old version.

To fix this, Right-Click on your Azure project and select Properties. Under the Application tab, you'll see a button to Update your Azure SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I got this after upgrading Azure SDK from 2.0 to 2.2. I was able to fix by:

1. Right-Clicking Azure project and selecting Properties. Update Azure SDK as per the Application tab. Thanks to rattrick1's answer.
2. Right click to Manage NuGet Packages. On the left click Updates and update WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.